# How to retrieve all custom posts from all the categories in portfolio

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created custom post type portfolio in wordpress. I have created categories like web-design, logo design, e-commerce, photography... etc. I have retrieved all these category as the navigation menu in portfolio template file (assigned to the portfolio page). Now  I want there should be a link(view all) in the navigation menu which will retrieve all the posts from all the categories in portfolio. Basically I want a way for making default category which will retrieve all the posts. Can anybody please help me!!!

Comment: Are all the categories you wish to retrieve for this page from the same post type?

Comment: Yes all these categories belongs to portfolio

Comment: Easy enough then, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

So, basically, you want to create a Custom Post Type Archive page.

A way to achieve this, as explained [at WPBeginner.com](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-post-types-archive-page-in-wordpress/), is like the following:

1. **Create a custom page template** (the PHP file could have any name you want) and **Add the Template Name comment** at the beginning of the file:

   `<?php /* Template Name: Custom Post Type Archive */ ?>`
2. Create a custom loop:

   ```
   <?php 
       /* Template Name: Custom Post Type Archive */ 
       get_header(); 
   ?>

   <?php
       global $query_string;
       query_posts($query_string . "post_type={YOUR-CUSTOM-POST-TYPE}&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=10");
       if ( have_posts() ) : 
           while ( have_posts() ) : 
               the_post(); 
   ?>

   <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
   <?php the_excerpt(); ?>


   <?php 
           endwhile; 
       endif; 
   ?>
   <div class="navigation">
      <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('Previous entries') ?></div>
      <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Next entries') ?></div>
   </div>
   <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

   <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
   <?php get_footer();?>
   ```
3. Create a new page and select the template you just created in the Page Attributes box

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the archive page template to list them all then.  Try going to http://yourdomain.com/portfolio and see if that brings it up.  You will need to have enabled archives for the post type when you created it though.  Look for `'has_archive' => true,` if you created the post type manually by dropping in the code in your `functions.php` file.  If you see that, but its set to "false", you'll need to change it to true.

You could also create a custom archive template for this post type if you wanted to.  If you create a new file in your theme directory called `archive-portfolio.php` and then put a custom loop in there the post type will automatically target that template file when accessing the post type archive.

Then to link from your nav menu to this archive, just create a custom menu item in your menu editor with the url http://yourdomain.com/portfolio.  You won't need to create any sort of "default" category if you take advantage of the post type archives.

Let me know if you have any other questions.